# Airflow s3 fatal error: Unable to locate credentials when copying files from another company's bucket to ours

Tags: airflow

I'm able to run the following command locally which is copying files from another company's bucket to our bucket:

```
aws s3 sync s3://client_export/other_company/pages/date={{ next_ds }}  s3://dev/our_company/pages
```

however when trying to run the commands in airflow locally I see the error `Unable to locate credentials`.

This is my task (**script** has the aws command I mentioned earlier):

```
files_to_s3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='get_files',
    bash_command=script,
    dag=dag)

files_to_s3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up AWS Credentials.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: Are there airflow instructions on where this would go?